# apache name virtual host - two domains and SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm trying to setup Apache(2.2.3) to run two websites with SSL using both different domains and IP addresses. Both websites run fine on port 80 but when I tried to enable SSL for website2 I get a ssl_error_bad_cert_domain error; website2 picks up the SSL cert for website1.

Here is my setup in httpd.conf:

```
# Website1
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.1:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.1:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.website1.org
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.1:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.1:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/website1.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/website1.key
</VirtualHost>

# Website2
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.2:80

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.2:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/chart
ServerName www.website2.org
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.2:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.2:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/website2.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/website2.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Update: 
In answer to Shane (this wouldn't fit in comment box) here is the output from apachectl -S:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.10.2:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.website2.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1033)
         port 80 namevhost www.website2.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1033)

192.168.10.2:443      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server bogus_host_without_reverse_dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1040)
         port 443 namevhost bogus_host_without_reverse_dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1040)

192.168.10.1:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.website1.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1017)
         port 80 namevhost www.website1.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1017)

192.168.10.1:443      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server bogus_host_without_reverse_dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1024)
         port 443 namevhost bogus_host_without_reverse_dns (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1024)

wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          192.168.10.1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: What output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: Can you confirm your .website2.org is resolved to 192.168.10.2?

Answer (score 1):

SSL vhosts are not NameVirtualHosts - they're IP-based vhosts.

Remove the `NameVirtualHost *:443` from your config.

Comment: I don't have `NameVirtualHost *:443` in my httpd.conf file.

Comment: You have **two**. Remove them.

Comment: I removed both and restarted apache but the website2 is still inheriting the SSL cert from website1.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.1:443
```

and

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.10.2:443
```

It doesn't make sense to activate the name based virtual hosting stuff of Apache for SSL/TLS connections or you'd like to use the SNI extension.

Comment: I removed those lines, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please remove the _default_ section in your ssl.conf file as well (see Shane Madden's comment)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it working. I had to move the ssl configuration out of httpd.conf and setup two virtualhosts in ssl.conf.

**httpd.conf**

```
# Website1
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.1:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.website1.org
</VirtualHost>

# Website2
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.2:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/chart
ServerName www.website2.org
</VirtualHost>
```

**ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.1:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
ServerAdmin you@your-site.com
ServerName www.website1.org
SSLEngine On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:
+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/website1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/website1.key
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.10.2:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/chart/"
ServerAdmin you@your-site.com
ServerName www.website2.org
SSLEngine On
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:
+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/website2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/website2.key
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is more or less what everyone here tried to recommend ;-) . Apache includes different files for configuration purposes. So its required to check all of them or to get a output of "apache2ctl -S". Anyway I like the way most administrators are going to split the configuration into different files. So you keep the overview about all the different settings (usually).

Answer (score 1):

Now that Apache2 handles named based virtualhosts for both `HTTP` *AND* `HTTPS` I would recommend setting your domains up in their own config file. Just as Apache does now with it's "sites-available/sites-enabled" config directories. Place both your `http` and `https` declarations in one file and either save that file to the "sites-enabled" directory or save wherever you want and sym-link it.

Like:
**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/Website_ONE.com.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName Website_ONE.com
  #if you want to redirect to https: 
  Redirect permanent / https://Website_ONE.com/
  DocumentRoot /WWW/Website_ONE.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName Website_ONE.com
  DocumentRoot /WWW/Website_ONE.com/ 

  ### SSL Setup ###
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_ONE.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_ONE.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_ONE.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Then: **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/Website_TWO.com.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName Website_TWO.com
  #if you want to redirect to https: 
  Redirect permanent / https://Website_TWO.com/
  DocumentRoot /WWW/Website_TWO.com/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName Website_TWO.com
  DocumentRoot /WWW/Website_TWO.com/ 

  ### SSL Setup ###
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_TWO.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_TWO.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/SSL_conf/Website_TWO.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

These files can, as I said, be kept anywhere - providing they are safe (i.e. readable by only the people that need access) - and linked into the *sites-enabled* folder. Same with the key files and all that. It makes it easier IMHO to keep track of your virtualhosts if all the config is in a file named after the domain. 
BTW, I would use absolute paths in the your config vs relative - as you did in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or commenting out  the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` block in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

Comment: I tried this too, then stopped and started apache but the problem still exists.

Comment: Has Apache *ever* presented the correct certificate?  Say, when you access the site with a SNI-capable browser?

Comment: No, I've been hitting the site w/ Firefox 11, latest Chrome, IE 9 and never get correct cert. If I modify my httpd.conf to list website2 before website1 then the issue is reversed website2 has the correct cert but website1 now inherits website2 cert.

Comment: Oh.. old Apache!  What do your `Listen` directives look like?

Comment: Seriously, this is a whole lot easier in IIS.Within httpd.conf: `Listen 80`, within ssl.conf: `Listen 443`.

Comment: Let's split those up to `Listen 192.168.10.1:80`, `Listen 192.168.10.2:80`, `Listen 192.168.10.1:443`, and `Listen 192.168.10.2:443`.

Answer (score 0):

You need ServerName www.server[1|2}.com in  section

Answer (score 0):

If you really run apache 2.2.3 the problem is that you cannot do name-based Virtual Hosting on SSL, because your mod_ssl doesn't support it.

You need apache version 2.2.12 or later for that.

You can however use ip-based virtual hosting. The solution you posted is actually doing that (two sites on two different ip adresses)

Answer (score -1):

You can not use vhosts with SSL unless you use a fairly recent development called SNI.
You could also use a wildcard cert (e.g. *.myhostname.com) if all your TLDs are the same.

For more detail, see:

- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts
- http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Apache2/SSL_and_Name_Based_Virtual_Hosts

Comment: I thought it was possible as long as you have different IPs?

Comment: Yes, of course, but then you are not using name based virtual hosts :)
With name based vhosts, you are attaching several names to a single ip and telling the server how to sort them out.

I've been through the same process you are now going through... although there are ways around it, they are not yet reliable or common.

Comment: Do other solutions exist? I'd rather not run two instances of apache.

Comment: @BrillPappin There aren't several names on any of those IP/port combinations?

Comment: Those two links I posted above should give you all the info an options you need.

I think pretty much the only way your going to get what you want is if all the domains have the same TLD so you can use a while-card cert.

However, you should not take my word as the last word, go check those links for other options.

Comment: While it's true you can't do name based virtual hosting over ssl without sni support, that's not what the above config is trying to achieve. It configures vhosts on seperate IP's/ports which is acceptable.

Comment: From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html - "..unless you are using a mod_ssl version without SNI support (standard in Apache releases since 2.2.12)..."